# OpenCart custom product title tag

Tags: php, controller, opencart

I want to display the category name on the products details page within title tag.

Example:

```
<title>Category name | Subcategory name | Product name</title>
```

The current setting is (catalog/controler/product/product.php):

```
$this->document->setTitle($product_info['name']);
```

Comment: Hmm, that's nice idea. Let us know how did You achieve it. Good luck!

Comment: @shadyyx Please see Thomas Lang's answer below in this question.
This script generates breadcrumbs-like string. Feel free to ask me anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do multiple things to achieve this.

The category info is being fetched somewhere around line 20:

```
foreach (explode('_', $this->request->get['path']) as $path_id) {
```

You could add each category's name to a variable and add that variable to the settitle part:

Just add the variable before the foreach:

```
$category_title_string = "";
foreach (explode('_', $this->request->get['path']) as $path_id) {
            if (!$path) {
                $path = $path_id;
            } else {
                $path .= '_' . $path_id;
            }

            $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

//Then add the cat name to the string:
$category_title_string.= $category_info['name'] . ' - ';
```

After this just change the settitle to:

```
$this->document->setTitle($category_title_string.' '.$product_info['name']);
```